# Is there software that will do reverse geocoding to convert photographs' GPS locations to addresses?

Tags: reverse-geocoding

I am using a standalone GPS tracker that produces GPX files and then clock-sync photos with it using Microsoft Pro Photo Tools. This works pretty well. But I was also using a feature of Pro Photo Tools called "Get location text" which uses the latitude/longitude information from EXIF and translates it using Windows Live services to actuall addresses. At least it used to, but stopped recently, probalby because of some change of the online API or whatever, and a lack of update for the software.

So, the questions is: do you know of any other software that can bulk translate location info into addresses and write that back into the photo's metadata?

I expect the solution to use Google Maps or Bing Maps APIs - both provide (reverse) geocoding world-wide and publicly, and work quite well through their websites. I find it hard to believe that no one has created an app yet that would do this in bulk for photos.

Comment: I added an answer at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20832/is-there-software-that-will-do-reverse-geocoding-to-convert-photographs-gps-loc/20836#20836

Comment: I recently extracted the lat/longs from a 1000 or so images with Python.  Then you could feed these into a reverse-geocoder.

Comment: Being quite desperate at the time of writing the question, I developed a simple proxy service that takes in requests from Pro Photo Tools, translates them into Google Maps queries and sends the answers back to the app. Anyone interested can find the code in my private repository here: https://github.com/TripleEmcoder/Archive/tree/master/other/MapPointEmulator - be warned however, that I stopped using that in favor of Lightroom, so it might not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

geosetter can do it.  I liked Pro Photo Tools much better, but as you pointed out, it no longer works.  The biggest difference for me is the sublocation field.  Pro Photo Tools put an addess in sublocation.  geosetter at this point just repeats the location field (city).  Pretty useless IMHO.

My understanding is Lightroom 4 now does reverse geocoding using google maps, which does have street level information.  I haven't downloaded LR 4 yet.

Comment: In the end I just went with Lightroom, as I also bought it for post-processing. Just works, and has quite nice tooling to match photos with a GPX track.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Google's GeoCode, you can make an HTTP request to google's:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + "&sensor=false

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this answer isn't really useful for someone just looking to geocode their photos, without programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Phatch](http://photobatch.wikidot.com/), in particular the [Geotag action](http://photobatch.wikidot.com/action-geotag); this could *maybe* give you something to build upon. Phatch is open-source and cross-platform, written in Python.

Answer (score 1):

[PicGPS.com](http://PicGPS.com) is a powerful tool that can get a street address out of any picture taken with a mobile device (“Location services” and “Geo Tagging” has to be turned on).

Answer (score -2):

https://geocode.xyz/ will do reverse geocoding - worldwide.

In your case you can get json data with this api call:
https://geocode.xyz/" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + "?json=1

Bulk reverse geocoding options are also available at https://geocode.xyz/batch

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this answer isn't really useful for someone just looking to geocode their photos, without programming skills.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".